# How to return department information from outlook contacts

Tags: python, outlook

I am trying to look up an outlook contact on GAL using python and return their department information (which is tied to their outlook account in the system). I can access the list of contacts and search based on name but I can't find a way to return department. Would it be possible to access that information through python at all?

```
import win32com.client
o = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application")
ns = o.GetNamespace("MAPI")

adrLi = ns.AddressLists.Item("Global Address List")
contacts = adrLi.AddressEntries

nameAliasDict = {}

for i in contacts:
    Name = i.Name
    x = ?   #Not sure what to make x equal to in order to make it department information
    if Name == 'FirstN LastN':
        print(x)
```

I know that the department information is attached to the Outlook contact because it shows up in a table whenever I try and send an email to someone and search their name.

Comment: You should check to see what kind of attributes are provided by looking at `object.__dict__`. Namely, please do `print("adrLi has: ", adrLi.__dict__); print("contacts has: ", contacts.__dict__);` and post the results here if you don't find your solution.

Comment: @musikreck this is what I got:                                                             Contacts has:  {'_oleobj_': <PyIDispatch at 0x031BCC90 with obj at 0x031C9C54>}

============ RESTART: H:/SecondRotation/python/access outlook.py ============
adrList has:  {'_oleobj_': <PyIDispatch at 0x0349BA18 with obj at 0x034ABC24>}

Comment: Yuck. Sorry I asked, haha. Can you do `for i in ns.AddressLists: print(i)`?

Comment: @musikreck I get these two lines printed 5 times in a row: <win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Outlook 14.0 Object Library.AddressList instance at 0x54383024>
<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Outlook 14.0 Object Library.AddressList instance at 0x54384368>

Comment: Ok, I can't seem to install the `win32com` module to test this myself. But it does look like the `Department` property *exists*. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._contactitem.department.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not loop through all entries in an address book container - some GAL containers can contain 100,000+ entries. Use `Namespace.CreateRecipient` / `Recipient.Resolve`. This will have the same effect as typing the name in the To edit box in Outlook and hitting Ctrl+K to resolve it. Once you have the resolved Recipient object, call `Recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().Department.` Be prepared to handle errors and `AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser()` returning null.